# Intel MIC offload pragma error

Tags: intel, pragma, intel-mic

What's this error? Couldn't find anything useful googling* about it :/

```
error: this pragma must immediately precede a statement
              #pragma offload target(mic) \
                      ^
```

Edit 1:
This is my pragma:

```
#pragma offload target(mic) \
            in (v1: length(B)) \
            in (v2, v3: length(A) \
            inout(v4, v5, v6: length(A))
```

Comment: The pragma is documented here: http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/doclib/iss/2013/compiler/cpp-lin/GUID-EAB414FD-40C6-4054-B094-0BA70824E2A2.htm

You seem to not use it correctly. Could you show the following lines?

Comment: Please show more lines. What statement follows the pragma?

Comment: The error says "this pragma must immediately precede a statement". In other words, there must be a statement of some kind immediately following the pragma. What follows your pragma? Is it a statement?

Comment: I got it. -.- Notice the missing parenthesis of the second "in".